# Fluttter dynamic pageview.builder (Frontend)

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, frontend

I have a problem with my PageView.Builder in Flutter. The error is

> "The following assertion was thrown during performResize(): Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height."

which is understandable. In my code,

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [

            //....
            SizedBox(
              height: 25,
            ),
            PageView.builder(
                controller: _pageController,
                itemCount: 400,
                onPageChanged: (value) {//....
                },
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding://.... 
 //....
                        SizeTransition(
                            sizeFactor: _animation,
                            child: Column(
                  //Here is another column with stuff which should expand when I press the Icnbtn
                              ),
                            ],
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Row( // Rest of the Widgets in the Column
```

it is noticeable that I have a SizeTransition in my Container. I want to make the entire Container "horizontally scrollable". Inside the Container is a week and with the scrolling I can switch between the weeks...

The Container is then in a Column with widgets above and below the Container. If I now wrap an Expanded around the PageView.builder or a simple SizedBox with a SingleChildScrollView, it is either no longer dynamic, meaning, when I open the SizeTransition, I have to scroll, instead of the Container simply enlarging, or, with an Expanded, the Widget becomes too large, or the subsequent Widgets are extremely shifted downwards. So it seems to "reserve" the space for the content of the SizeTransition. But now I want this Container to be really dynamically expandable, that I just have the subsequent widgets docked with the SizeTransition and just as little do I want to have the content of the Container scrollable. How does that work, or is it even possible?